# Swift, CoreData, FetchRequest, 2 Entities, ManyToMany, with GroupBy, Having Count and Sort, How?

Tags: swift, core-data, group-by, many-to-many, nsfetchrequest

I have a hard time with CoreData requests. Using some SQL derivate I'd get along. But here I need some help.

I have two entities with manyToMany relationships. It looks like this:

```swift
Repeatable (name: String, type: Int16, entries: [Entry])
Entry      (id: UUID, createdAt: Date, repeatables: [Repeatable])
```

I want to get a list of repeatables belonging to more than 1 entry, ordered by the count of associations

In SQL it would look like this:

```sql
SELECT rep.Z_PK, COUNT(rep.Z_PK) as count FROM ZREPEATABLE AS rep
INNER JOIN Z_1REPEATABLES as link
ON rep.Z_PK = link.Z_2REPEATABLES
INNER JOIN ZENTRY AS entry
ON entry.Z_PK = link.Z_1ENTRIES
GROUP BY rep.Z_PK
HAVING count > 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```

---

### Can I do this with Core Data in swift ? How does the code look like ?

Edit:

I came up with this (part of solution):

```swift
let somethingED = NSExpressionDescription()
somethingED.expression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "entries.@count.id")
somethingED.name = "countSth"
somethingED.expressionResultType = .integer64AttributeType

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Repeatable")
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name", somethingED]
fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["entries"]
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "$countSth > 1")

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

do {
    let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    print(result)
} catch{
    print("error fetching: \(error)")
}
```

The problem with this solution... I don't know how to sort this. I always end up with an error. Also this is no group-by + having construct. So, I think, well, ok, if this works, I don't need no group-by. BUT still I'd like to know how or if this is possible with group-by + having predicate ?!

---

Edit 2:

So in the comments @pbasdf [linked this from wwdc 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019-230/?time=1087) (+1 for that). It describes exactly my use case and provides a perfect solution... BUT... it's for iOS 13, but I want to support iOS 12 as well (iPhone 6 for example). And so I finally came up with this solution: have an `entriesCount` property + on each save update that value.
Now saving is a little bit slower but reading will be ultra fast because there's no table join, group by or count needed in the query.

```
    public override func willSave() {
        let newValue =  Int16(self.entries?.count ?? 0)
        if countEntries != newValue, changedValues()[#keyPath(Repeatable.countEntries)] == nil, !isDeleted {
            countEntries = newValue
        }
        super.willSave()
    }
```

Comment: I think the group by and having clauses are both do-able.  But the order by is a struggle.  Basically CoreData only likes sorting on attributes, not computed values like your count.

Comment: Ah, hmm. So there's no way there ?

Comment: I don’t know of any way.  If that sort order is important, you could either sort after fetching, or store the count as an attribute and update it whenever the relationship count changes.

Comment: ... might be a good use of [NSDerivedAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsderivedattributedescription)?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more how to use NSDerivedAttribute ? Maybe give me an example ?

Comment: Not used them myself, but the WWDC2019 Core Data video has a demo - almost exactly  your use case - counting relationships.  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019-230/?time=1087).

Comment: yeah. this is exactly my use case. it's perfect. except it's iOS 13. :D and I was targeting iOS 12. damn it :D but big big thanks to you for finding and providing the link with the correct timestamp ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. You would create an [NSFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest) and customize its `sortDescriptors` and `predicate` properties to get the result you want.

If you set up your core data relationships properly, there's no need to manually specify things like an "inner join". You simply set up the many-to-many relationship in the data model and then you can access those relationships directly in your predicate.

I don't know if your entire query is entirely translatable into a single fetch, but there's no need to restrict yourself to that. Once you've finished your fetch you can do further refinement/processing in a managed object context. That's the whole point of the CoreData ORM, you just work on the objects directly and don't worry about the underlying DB.

Comment: Sounds good. But how to customize the predicate properties to get my result, and fast (because this will be queried often), so I guess what I want is a single fetch. And of course I have my relationships set and everything modelled.